# recursion Think Python 2 exercise 5.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

This question regarding exercise 5.5 from Think Python 2 has been [asked and answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048933/understanding-recursion-in-python-2-think-python-exercise-5), but I still don't understand how this function works. Here's the function in question:

```
def draw(t, length, n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    angle = 50
    t.fd(length*n)
    t.lt(angle)
    draw(t, length, n-1)
    t.rt(2*angle)
    draw(t, length, n-1)
    t.lt(angle)
    t.bk(length*n)
```

I see a recursive loop here:

```
def draw(t, length, n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    angle = 50
    t.fd(length*n)
    t.lt(angle)
    draw(t, length, n-1)
```

After the function calls itself a sufficient number of times to cause n == 0, how does it move on to the next step, namely t.rt(2*angle)? Once n == 0, shouldn't the function return None and simply end? If not, where is returning to? The same thing happens again the next time it calls itself, and then the function continues to perform work long after the state n == 0 has been satisfied (twice!). I'm obviously missing a key concept here and would appreciate any light anyone can shed on this topic. Thanks in advance~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding recursion in Python 2 (Think Python, exercise 5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048933/understanding-recursion-in-python-2-think-python-exercise-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement returns execution of the program back to the line where the function that returned was called.

If you're not familiar with what a call stack is, think of it as a stack of functions - whenever something gets called, it's placed on top of the stack and that's what's running. When that returns, it's removed from the stack and so the function that called it (one below in the stack) is now the top, so that's where execution picks up again.

That particular function will return when n == 0 (so that's your base case), so once its recursive call `draw(t, length, n-1)` - and, by consequence, its subsequent recursive calls, since it won't finish execution until they do - reach that point, it'll move over to the next line.

Take a simpler function `foo(sum, n)` instead:

```
def foo(sum, n):
    if (n == 0):
        return sum
    sum += foo(sum, n-1)
    sum /= 2
    return foo(sum, n-1)
```

Whenever you call that, it won't move from `sum += foo(sum, n-1)` until that call and all of the recursive calls made return. This function is structurally comparable to the one you showed and it might help you visualize a little better what's going on.

Comment: So we can think of the procedures in a function like tasks written pieces of paper, which, after reading( calling), are put on top of a 'to do' pile (call stack). Each task effectively returns when finished and then you go to the piece of paper below. If, while performing that task you come across a task that calls for some side action, that task goes to the top of the stack until it's done. Like you're doing the dishes and the drain becomes clogged, so you switch your attention to unclogging the drain and then resume doing the dishes. Is this the gist?

Comment: By the way, although I think I understand your explanation for the function I posted, your 'simpler' function is way beyond me. I've never seen += used with a function with multiple arguments, so I'm not sure how to evaluate it. I added a print(sum) statement after sum += foo(sum, n-1), and after sum /=  2 to get an idea of what's happening, and then ran foo(10, 3). But I don't have enough characters left to report on what I found and ask more questions, so i'm going to start a new question thread using this example function, the alterations I've tried and what I've found. I hope thats ok~

Comment: Comparing the call stack to a "to do" pile should give you a good and actually very accurate idea of how it works. I am also guilty of not knowing what exactly the function I wrote would return, but `sum += foo(sum, n-1)` is shorthand for `sum = sum + foo(sum, n-1)`. The same goes for `/=`, `*=` and `-=`.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, @osuka_ ~ I understand what `+=` means and how it works with two variables, but not with a function with two arguments. I rewrote the program to reverse the arguments so foo is in the form `foo(n, sum)` everywhere it shows up. `sum` still increments with the `sum` argument. I added `mus = 3` as the first statement of the function and replaced `sum +=...` with `mus += foo(n-1, sum)` and added a `print(mus)` statement. `mus` still increments with `sum`. Why not with 'n-1`? What is the general rule for evaluating statements of this form? What if foo had three arguments?

Comment: Ahh, I found it! `return sum` assigns it. It seems that the function tunnels to the base case and gathers the rules of that 'to do' stack along the way before applying them. Now if I can only figure out why it still performs the recursing `n-1` tasks in descending order on the way down, and on the ascending order after it reaches the base case instead of just exhausting each `n-1` recursion until `n == 0` and then simply moving on to the next task. I built a stack diagram based on the output of the original function I posted, but I can't see to tease out the actual rules from it. My head hurts

Comment: Sometimes it's good to catch a break. It seems like you're getting there, but don't be too harsh on yourself if you seem to have hit a wall - recursion is one of those very abstract concepts that can be hard to wrap your head around at first.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a picture explaining this in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048933/understanding-recursion-in-python-2-think-python-exercise-5/39974778#39974778) , for a fast navigation here's my picture :

[image: Explanation]

Comment: Thanks! Great idea! I think something like this is exactly what I need. The only thing I would add when trying this myself is the actual statements being called in each stack instead of '...'. Juggling the statements in my mind makes my head spin. I'm looking forward to when this is all becomes second nature. I'd also love to know the 'why' of this order of operations, rather than just accepting it as a given, but I think a detour into more hardcore computer science will be necessary for that. Thanks again! Be good~

Comment: Dont worry at all , i've studied CS for 5 year since my 21y old, but since i dont use code in my actual job i have hard time too in this kind of exercices (code is all about everyday practice), also i dont think you will need to use this kind of recursive program in any average app/script you can do the same with loops if i'm right and loops are far better (PS : dont forget to upvote my answer if it helped you a bit :) )