# recursion of the form var += func(var, n-1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

TL/DR How do you evaluate statements of the form `var += func(var, n-1)`?

edit: By 'evaluate' I mean, how is the value being called by the right side of this statement determined. Within the function given below, `var += func(var, n-1)` always results in `sum += sum`. But why is `sum` always called? why not `sum += (n-1)`? What determines which value is called by the right side? With the help of a few responses, I think I figured it out (see below), but more light on the subject will always be appreciated. I've only been learning programming for a few days.

I [asked a question regarding a recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814341/recursion-think-python-2-exercise-5-5/39814559#39814559) and received an answer that I was satisfied with, but which raised several more questions. I've been looking through previous questions on the topic but I'm still missing  something. It feels like recursion is a fundamental concept that must be grasped completely to succeed with programming, so I'd like to keep asking questions until I figure it out. The answerer offered another example function for me to contemplate:

```
def foo(sum, n):
    if (n == 0):
        return sum
    sum += foo(sum, n-1)
    sum /= 2
    return foo(sum, n-1)
```

I've never seen += used with a function with multiple arguments and I have no idea how to evaluate this. I added `print(sum)` after `sum += foo(sum, n-1)` and `sum /= 2` to try and see what was happening. Running `foo(10, 3)` resulted in:

```
20
10.0
20.0
10.0
20.0
10.0
20.0
10.0
20.0
10.0
20.0
10.0
20.0
10.0
```

I decided to change the `+=` to `*=` to see if that would make what was happening more clear. This is that program:

```
def foo(sum, n):
    if (n == 0):
        return sum
    sum *= foo(sum, n-1)
    print(sum)
    sum /= 2
    print(sum)
    return foo(sum, n-1)

foo(10, 3)
```

It produced the following:

```
100
50.0
500.0
250.0
62500.0
31250.0
312500.0
156250.0
24414062500.0
12207031250.0
1907348632812500.0
953674316406250.0
9.094947017729283e+29
4.5474735088646414e+29
```

I can trace a few different interwoven patterns in this output, (i.e. the original sum 10 is called in the 1st, 2nd and 4th instances; the output is in groups of two recursions, two recursions, and three recursions; the output of `sum/2` feeds the input of the 3rd, 5th and 7th instances), but I can't seem to unravel it without knowing how to evaluate the `sum *= foo(sum, n-1)` or the original `sum += foo(sum, n-1)`.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question - what exactly is the problem with "evaluating" that line? The function is called first and its result is added the local value `sum`

Comment: There is nothing special about `+=` and recursion. You have an expression on the right-hand side, which is evaluated and then added to the object on the left. Recursive calls are no different there. For immutable types, `x += y` is just the same thing as `x = x + y`.

Comment: Apologies if I simply don't know enough to properly ask the question. I'm knew to all of this. Regarding evaluating, there are two arguments in `foo(sum, n-1)`. How is that added to `sum`? What is added to `sum`? I gathered from the output that it was only the `sum` argument that was added to `sum`, which leads to the second question: does the statement `sum += foo(sum, n-1)` call another instance of `foo(sum, n)`, and, if so, why does the function pass to `sum/2` before completely exhausting `n` at `n == 0` and calling `return`?

Answer (score 0):

In python, `x += y` is same as *`x = x + y` i.e. add `y` to the value of `x` and save to `x`*.

In your case, `sum += foo(sum, n-1)` means *add value returned by `foo(sum, n-1)` with `sum` and save it as `sum`*.

It similarly goes for `*=`, `-=`, etc. For example: `x *= y` means *multiply y with x and save it as x*. Hope that answered your question.

Read: [Augmented Assignment Statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) for more information.

Comment: *x += y is same as x = x + y*: only for immutable types. For mutable types, the option exists to alter the object in-place. So for lists, `+=` is the same as `list.extend()` followed by a re-bind of the name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question I have is this: what is the nature of the value returned by a function with multiple arguments that allows it to be added to a single variable? Does this form only work when the variable on the left side is also one of the arguments on the right side? What would be the output of `mus += foo(sum, n-1)`? And a follow-up question: in the above function, does the statement `sum += foo(sum, n-1)` call another instance of `foo(sum, n)`, and, if so, why does the function pass to `sum/2` before completely exhausting `n` at `n == 0` and calling return?

Answer (score 0):

While I still haven't figured exactly why the given function produces the output it does, I have finally figured the main question of the topic, namely, how to evaluate statements of the form `var += func(var, n-1)`.

While a statement of the form `x += y` is simple enough to understand, the function on the right side of the statement in question has multiple arguments. What I couldn't understand was which value from `func(var, n-1)` was to be used and how that was determined. So I experimented. I added a new first statement `mus = 3` to the function and replaced `sum += foo(sum, n-1)` with `mus += foo(sum, n-1)` and printed the result. I reversed the arguments positions in the function and checked the result. And I added a third argument to the function and checked that. Every time, the value of `sum` was called in every variation of `sum += foo(sum, n-1)`.

And then I deleted `sum` from `return sum` and ran it, which produced a `TypeError` and then it clicked. So I changed it to `return n-1`, and then that became the value that was called in `sum += foo(sum, n-1)`. I changed it to the new third variable I had added, `return x` and then that was the value called.

So it seems that in order to evaluate statements of the form `var += func(var, n-1)`, you must check to see which argument is returned in the base case when the function is run. Corrections would be greatly appreciated if I'm wrong~